# Generic XML to Object mapping

Tags: c#, xml, converters

I receive an xml message, translate it into a different format, and then send it on. The messages range from around 40 lines to 600 or more lines of xml, averaging at around 100 lines. I can receive multiple messages a second, but average around 15 to 20 a minute in heavy times.

Since the xml provides new information for an existing application, I have created a class that mimics the structure of the output xml. The object will create the output xml, only including items that have changed, and it will translate input terminology into language the consuming application will understand. What I am having difficulty figuring out is how to easily map the incoming xml to the object.

The incoming xml uses several different templates that determine the format of each node. I am trying to create a map that can determine that if the node is named n, then it needs to go to object m. Below is a simplified example of what I am trying to do.

Message 1

```
<Incoming>
    <Name>Bob</Name>
    <City>Seattle</City>
    <Hobby>Fishing</Hobby>
</Incoming>
```

Message 2

```
<Incoming>
    <Name>Bob</Name>
    <Employment>
        <JobTitle>Sales</JobTitle>
        <Manager>Jessica</Manager>
    </Employment>
    <Hobby>Reading</Hobby>
</Incoming>
```

This would go into an object similar to this:

```
public Customer
{
    public String Name{get; set;}
    public Address CustomerAddress{get;set;}
    public Employer CustomerEmployer{get;set;}
    public List<String> Hobbies{get;set;}
}

public Address
{
    public String StreetAddress{get;set;}
    public String City{get;set;}
    public String State{get;set;}
    public String Zip{get;set;}
}

public Employer
{
    public String Company{get;set;}
    public String Position{get;set;}
    public String Manager{get;set;}
    public Address CompanyAddress{get;set;}
}
```

Without creating a long Switch Case, does anyone have ideas on how to best get the information from xml to object? Because of the amount of information, I am being a bit more conscious of the time cost for processing.

I've thought about coming up with a mapping; something like

```
<Name>Customer:Name</Name>
<City>Customer:Address:City</City>
```

However, there is the problem of how to map items that are in a list, like Hobby. There is also the problem of how to quickly consume the mapping. The only thing I can think of is for each object to process one part of the map to determine the path, although this sounds expensive.

I'm not so worried about the duplicate Addresses at different levels. This data is an example. In my actual xml, I don't think I have any duplicates.

I appreciate any assistance or ideas people have. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is there a reason built-in XML serialization won't work for you? See MSDN on System.Xml.Serialization. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.aspx

Comment: Do you have an XSD for the XML? If so, use that XSD with System.Xml.Serialization as @MarcL. proposed. The XSD allows you to specify required and not required fields etc. You object will then be populated with the fields that are specified, others will be null. You can also apply custom rules as to what to serialize and what not when you pass your object on.

Comment: Thank you for the responses. The reason I do not serialize from the object to the outgoing xml is that I only include values (or objects) that have changed, to save on processing at the consuming object. As for serializing from the incoming xml, I am trying to keep the converting class generic, so it can accept xml in any format using an arbitrary naming convention. This was why I thought using a mapping xml for each application who's xml the converter will be consuming was a good way to go. It's just proving to be a bit more tricky than I expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to use reflection and recursion to access properties using a map. I set up the map path like this:

```
map = new Dictionary<string, string>();
map.Add("Name", "Name");
map.Add("Street", "Address.Address");
map.Add("City", "Address.City");
map.Add("State", "Address.State");
map.Add("Zip", "Address.Zip");
map.Add("Activity", "*Hobbies.Hobby");
map.Add("Years", "*Hobbies.Years");
```

The asterisk indicates this is a list and requires a key. I add the key in processing, so the full path I send in is something like "*Hiking.Hobbies.Years", with Hiking being the key. The method that processes this follows:

```
private void SetValue(object source, String path, String value)
{
    if (path.Contains('.'))
    {
        //  If this is not the ending Property, continue recursing
        int index = path.IndexOf('.');
        String property = path.Substring(0, index);

        object nextSource;
        if(property.Contains("*"))
        {
            path = path.Substring(index + 1);
            index = path.IndexOf('.');
            String dictionaryName = path.Substring(0, index);
            property = property.Substring(1);

            IDictionary list = source.GetType().GetProperty(dictionaryName).GetValue(source, null) as IDictionary;
            if (!list.Contains(property))
            {
                Type[] arguments = list.GetType().GetGenericArguments();
                list.Add(property, Activator.CreateInstance(arguments[1]));
            }

            nextSource = list[property];                    
        }
        else
            nextSource = source.GetType().GetProperty(property).GetValue(source, null);

        SetValue(nextSource, path.Substring(index + 1), value);
    }
    else
    {
        PropertyInfo pi = source.GetType().GetProperty(path);
        pi.SetValue(source, Convert.ChangeType(value, pi.PropertyType), null);
    }
}
```

I hope this helps someone out.